# background-image set via javascript is not being cached by Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, css, google-chrome, caching

On my web site, while the page is loaded, some javascript detects the screen resolution and then sets the body's background to be a url, using this code:

```
var url = "http://site.com/get_background/" + width + "/" + height;

var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];            

body.style.background = "#000000 url(" + url + ") fixed top center";
```

At the url `get_background/`, an image is served using the following PHP code:

```
     $etag = md5_file($image);
     $lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($image)) . ' GMT';

     header("Content-type: $mime");
     header("ETag: \"{$etag}\"");
     header("Last-Modified: $lastModified");
     header('Cache-Control: max-age=28800');

     $image = readfile($image);
     imagejpeg($image);

    imagejpeg($image);
```

In firefox, this all works as expected. However in Chrome, each time a page on this site loads, the image seems to get loaded once again rather than just being cached and served.

If I move the code for setting the background to an external css file, then it works as expected in chrome, however if I put it in javascript, then it seems to make Chrome refresh the image.

What should I do about it? As the screen resolution needs to be detected via javascript, therefore the code must be put in the JS. Is there a way to force chrome to cache the image even though its loaded via javascript?

Comment: "In firefox, this all works as expected" -- why do you expect browser won't request it again? Which header of 3 you used should, from your point of view, prevent browser of re-requesting it?

Comment: Not sure if this will make any difference but how about adding just a class to the body tag and defining the images in your stylesheet? I'm assuming it's only half a dozen or so images you have?

Comment: And, as it was yesterday - you, as a high rep user, was too lazy to google and find out that using "php image cache" search query you'll get hundreds of worked solutions (assuming that you're too lazy to read http specifications)

Comment: @zerkms This issue is specific to google chrome, its working as expected in firefox, and I haven't been able to find a solution by googling or I won't have asked here.

Comment: @BillyMoat No, that's not possible, there are a lot of resolutions to support.

Comment: @Click Upvote: It doesn't work as expected (the fact it works in FF is just a coincidence). The code you've presented doesn't contain any header that should command a browser to cache image. That is why I asked you why do you think it should cache, but you ignored my question.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, I've added `header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');` right after the Last-modified header, but it doesn't seem to have any effect in chrome either

Comment: @Click Upvote: have you read what `Cache-Control: max-age=0` means? Do you always add some random things and expect your code to work?

Comment: @Click Upvote: nothing personal. I've asked a question - have you read what `Cache-Control: max-age=0` means? It means the opposite - to not use cache at all. PS: probably, yes, I have some personal issues with lazy "programmers", who don't bother spending couple of minutes in google to find something like http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/how-to-cache-images-generated-by-php.html

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for that, the new headers fixed it. If you wanna post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully cache the response you need to set `Expires` header in the initial response and on next responses you need to check existence of `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` request header.

And if it exists - you need to respond back with `304`

More details may be found at http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/how-to-cache-images-generated-by-php.html

Comment: I only head to use the 3 headers given in that file, i.e `header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime(" 2 day")));` and it worked

Comment: @Click Upvote: it's not a robust solution. You need to have response with `304` as it said in that article. At least that is how it is supposed to be done in a correct way (and that is how all webservers are implemented)